What would happen if a natural disaster occurred on election Day?
Two large hurricanes have recently swept though a couple of swing statess.
What if it had happened on election Day instead? This could cause massive disruption. Voting places might need to be shut down and even if it remained open, people might not be able to safely make it to vote. In the worst case, ballots could be destroyed by the storm.
Given how close the election is, such an event could easily change the outcome of the election it disenfranchise large groups of voters.
What would generally happen if this was to occur? Is there any provisions for the election to be postponed due to an emergency? Has such an event occurred in history yet?

With your last question, are you asking “have elections ever been postponed anywhere”, or “have States ever postponed a US national election?”

IIRC, there was a county during the last national election where there was a problem with the voting machines on election day. They extended the voting hours later into the evening to accomodate.

NYC was having a primary election on 9/11. It was cancelled and postponed for three weeks

FWIW, there was a law review article written on this topic in 2018 (the suggested citation date for the article of 1905 is erroneous). https://scholarlycommons.law.emory.edu/elj/vol67/iss3/6/ It was oddly prescient, given that it was written prior to COVID although COVID did create some case law on state level changes in election laws and regulations due to exigent circumstances.

Not exactly on point, but in 2023, Turkey has an election without a hitch in May after an extremely severe earthquake in February. https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2023/05/23/turkey-election-earthquakes-erdogan-kilicdaroglu/

How is that to do with Politics, please? How is not purely about administration and logistics?

As a matter of practical politics, if a natural disaster occurring on the day of the election the affected state(s) would likely take emergency measures, like holding the polls open for as long as necessary and/or extending vote-by mail options or creating special ballot collection procedures. The individual states are solely responsible for guaranteeing the validity of the election, so there's nothing really stopping them from taking such emergency procedures. It might generate lawsuits contesting the election, obviously, but by law the states have until December 14th to ascertain the vote and submit their slate of electors, which should be more than enough time to account for even the most devastated areas. But in the worst-case scenario, in which ascertainment cannot be made or is intractably contested, the issue can be redressed at the joint session of Congress, with electors from the affected state(s) — or perhaps merely electors from affected regions of those states — can be challenged and excluded. The results will then be decided on the basis of the remaining electoral college votes.
There's a good bit of magical thinking about election day in the US, as though that date has some special significance beyond being a conventional cut-off for casting votes. There are good reasons to hold to that convention, but the states' primary goal is to ensure a valid and comprehensive ballot. If sticking to the specific date means that the ballot will be incomplete and impaired, then a state will likely break the convention to ensure the ballot. The election will definitely be contested if they don't; the best hope of successfully ascertainmaent lies in bending the rules.

I think the issue is around a disaster that occurs with little warning on election day and keeps people out of the polls all day long in areas of the country

@JoeW: I gathered. But I'm sure that if a hurricane hit Florida or a big earthquake hit California on election day, the state would take emergency measures to allow people to vote, even if that meant leaving to polls open for a week or more. Ultimately a court (and maybe Congress) would have to decide whether that was legitimate, but when it's clear that election day voting was compromised by a disaster (and thus illegitimate in its own right), I think courts would accept it.

But the idea of holding polls open as long as necessary when those polling sites in a large area could be unsafe for the entire election day and days after doesn't really make sense. It sounds like you are answering for a short period of time when the polls could be open on election day and not have to be opened days later.

@JoeW: I think we're having confusion over words. "Opening the polls" is not a physical act of opening some door; it's a declaration that that ballots are being accepted. 'Polls open' for early voting, 'polls open' for the mail-in voting. If a disaster strikes early in the morning of election day, the polls will still open even if the polling stations remain closed and inaccessible. The goal is to make sure to leave the polls open until everyone has a reasonable opportunity to cast their ballot.

@JoeW: If it takes a state a week or more after a disaster to ensure that everyone gets a chance to vote, a state could (and likely would) do that. The polls would be open for all that time, which doesn't;t mean that some building somewhere is open, but that the state is willing to collect ballots and count them as valid through that period.

Of course, with the results of most other states already announced, there will be a lot of people saying that the result of that state has been skewed because of that and whatnot. Lawsuits galore.

The issue is that it is federal law that decides when election day and state authorities don't have the power to extend how long people have to cast ballots, it would be up to congress not the states to extend the election. https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/7

@jcaron We already have that problem to some extent -- results of east coast states are announced while west coast polls are still open.

@JoeW: The Federal Government decides what day polls will be open, yes, but it doesn't explicitly determine the details of polling practice, and by the constitution all powers not explicitly vested in the Federal government devolve to the states and the people. This gives states a lot of leeway to determine best practices for its citizens. Regardless (as I said), this is what a state would likely do as a matter of practice, and then the legality of it would be settled in court challenges.

Yes, it does determine that the polls can't be open after election day and that is what matters. If you have a last minute disaster they are not going to be able to do last minute moves of polling places and even if they did it likely wouldn't be safe for people to travel to them. The bottom line if there is a disaster that impacts voting and it will be congress who decides how to resolve it not the states. There is a big difference between keeping polls open longer because of technical issues and after a major disaster.

@Joew: I'm always surprised by the odd conceptions people have about law. Law is words on paper that tell us what we are supposed to do, and how we can be punished if we don't. But the real world is messy, and in practice people do what they think is right — what they think they have to do — and face the law later if it becomes an issue. If a state thinks its population is being disenfranchised by a natural disaster it will take steps necessary to address that problem and face legal challenges when they come. That's how things work.

Again, the federal election controls election day, not the state government so it isn't up to the states to decide to open the election polls later in the month because of a disaster. In fact you can point to recent federal rulings to not extend voter registration deadlines due to hurricanes as an example of what will really happen. https://www.reuters.com/legal/two-us-judges-decline-extend-voter-registration-following-hurricanes-2024-10-10/

@JoeW: Again, legal literalism is not going to help you. (1) There's nothing currently stopping a state from opening the polls on election day and then extending polling access indefinitely. (2) States (like anyone else) are perfectly capable of breaking a law for good cause and then arguing their case later in court. You're being a bit silly here…

Nothing stopping a state other then the federal court system which includes the supreme court ordering them to stop and to not count any of the ballots that got cast after election day? There is plenty of precedent for the federal courts and supreme court ruling on federal elections at the state level. The supreme court has ordered states to stop counting/recounting ballots in the past and there is no reason to think that would change today.

@JoeW: You're still not getting it, but I don't think we should continue this discussion here.  I'll leave it up to readers to use their own common sense.

My last comment, is just a reminder that politics and common sense don't go hand in hand. A quick example is someone getting their voter registration challenged because the city changed the name of the street they live on.  "Reporter: Voters like Lakendra Graham. She said she lived on Confederate Avenue in Atlanta, the name of which the city changed with great fanfare to United Avenue in 2019. Not her fault she told the board in March." https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/tv-series/election-subversion-2024-waffle-house-last-week-tonight-with-john-oliver-transcript/
